# Where to include log properties file after converting the java code to jar file

Tags: java, tomcat, jar, log4j

I wrote the java package which includes many java files.

The log files are created when working in eclipse but i converted it to jar file and place it in apache tomcat and include the log properties file in classes folder...

But log is not getting generated...suggest me where should i include the log properties file....

Comment: Which logging framework are you trying to configure?  (Probably the META-INF/ directory, all the same).

Comment: How did you "place it in apache tomcat and include the log properties file in classes folder..."?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading from http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html:

> The default log4j initialization is particularly useful in web-server
>   environments. Under Tomcat 3.x and 4.x, you should place the
>   log4j.properties under the WEB-INF/classes directory of your
>   web-applications. Log4j will find the properties file and initialize
>   itself. This is easy to do and it works.

Hope this helps!